# AAD B2C SignUpOrSignIn with both verified Email AND verified Phone

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Usually we have a signup/signin with either email or phone, but I have a requirement to do signup/signin requiring both **verified email** and **verified phone number** as well.

I tried to set this up using default 'User Flows', with MFA for phone/sms enabled, but the number is not accessible via the graph API call for phoneMethods, if it were, I could have also copied the number to the profile (which would mean that it was a verified phone number). Further on the same, enabling Authentication Method, OR even updating (separating phone number with a space char for code and number) the phone number on the profile page causes the phone number to appear via the phoneMethods graph API call, but not before then.

Can someone who's done this before share some insights on their approach or probably share the custom xml policy if possible? I did look into the github sample policies [https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies], but I guess there is none with BOTH.

**[Edit on the above]**

Based on Wes' input, I ended up creating a technical profile as per below and used it into my UserJourney -> Orchestration step, post the PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify step as per below (apologies on the formatting):

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="extension_PhoneNumber" />
    </PersistedClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="extension_PhoneNumber"/>
        </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Ofcourse, the "extension_PhoneNumber" was setup in ClaimsSchema as per below:

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_PhoneNumber">
    <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
```

Hope this helps someone...
Cheers! ;)

PS: Appreciate any updates to any of the above comments to make it correct/better.

Comment: Could you share your entire sign up flow? I am trying to do JUST phone verify, and reading this is great insight.

Answer (score 4):

I have done something somewhat similar to this but in my case I verified a new MFA number as my flow resets the users MFA number, but hopefully this will give you an idea. As far as an approach, you could take the standard login flow from the samples -> add verify the email step -> add verify phone number step. I do not know your level of experience with custom policies, but I believe using the sample custom policy for sign in as an initial template will be your best starting place. Then add the two orchestration steps for verification in. Here are slightly modified excerpts from my implementation.

```
 <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signin" Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewPhoneFactor" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-Verify" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" Order="5" Type="SendClaims" />
```

Steps 1,2 and 5 should be able to be copied directly from the samples with a small change of outputting the email as a read only claim to be used to verify(see below steps).

Your local account signin will need to add a transform that generates the readonly email from sign in name if you choose this route.
So in your local account signin you will have

```
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

just after your output claims and the transform that is being used will be as follows:

```
 <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Be sure to define your readonly claim in the claimstypes section:

```
      <ClaimType Id="readOnlyEmail">
    <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText />
    <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

This is just a simple claim copy transformation.

Steps 3 and 4, which do each of the verification, have the technical profiles similar to below:

```
  <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
      <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.EmailPage</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

This will verify the email that was used to sign in, then the following orchestration step will be to verify the MFA.

You will have to make changes to this next  technical profile, but the basic idea will be the same as with email, here is a starting point :

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-Verify">
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

The end result would be:

1. User logs in with email and password
2. User clicks button to verify the email used during login
3. User verifies phone number
4. Claims are sent and journey completes

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply to my question, it did help me with a bit of direction.
I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer, not enough reputation points! :P

I did end up configuring the PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify, but was missing persisting the claim. So had to come up with something as per below in a new TechnicalProfile:

`<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="extension_PhoneNumber" />`

Hope this helps someone who's blocked by it.